# Inter library dependency inside a workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I have create a new angular 6 workspace with an application and added two libraries named library1, library2.
library2, uses a module from library1 like below

```
import {Library1Module} from "library1"
```

compile library1 using `ng build --project=library1`

This works

compile library2 using `ng build --project=library2`

This fails with error

```
* getting exception projects/library2/src/lib/library2.module.ts(3,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'library1'.
```

How can I use internal library in cli workspace

Answer (score 0):

In `projects/library2/tsconfig.lib.json`, add the following in `compilerOptions`

```
compilerOptions: {
   ...
   "paths": {
      "library1": [
         "../../../dist/library1"
       ]
    }
    ...
 }
```